# Library / function for computation of molecular mass / molecular weight in C

Tags: software, elements

We are looking for a function to be used for computing the molecular mass / molecular weight / formula weight in C, either in a library or standalone.  So far we have found the following implementations:

- R language: [shown here](https://rdrr.io/cran/OrgMassSpecR/src/R/MolecularWeight.R) (limited implementation)
- Matlab: [shown here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26139-molecular-weight-calculator-function?focused=5141702&tab=function) (full implementation)
- Python: [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796431/calculating-molecular-weight-in-python) (issue is discussed, preliminary implementation)
- Perl: [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563032/calculating-molecular-weight-in-perl) (for protein molecular weights)

Ideally, the function would be able to handle a string input which could be either an element or compound.  In the latter case, the total number of each element forming the compound would be determined prior to atomic mass look-up.

Comment: For Python, [periodictable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/periodictable) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you [download AmberTools](http://ambermd.org/GetAmber.php), under the `AmberTools/src/sff` directory, there is `atomic_number.{h,c}`. Note that this code is under the GPL.

`atomic_number.h`:

```c
#ifndef ATOMIC_NUMBER_H
#define ATOMIC_NUMBER_H

#include "sff.h"

// Atomic number 0 has mass 0 and is a lone pair or extra point

#define NUM_ATOMS 119

const static REAL_T ATOMIC_MASS[NUM_ATOMS] = 
   {
     0.0, 1.0079, 4.0026, 6.941, 9.0122, 10.811, 12.0107,
     14.0067, 15.9994, 18.9984, 20.1797, 22.9898, 24.3050,
     26.9815, 28.0855, 30.9738, 32.065, 35.453, 39.948,
     39.0983, 40.078, 44.9559, 47.867, 50.9415, 51.9961,
     54.9380, 55.845, 58.9331, 58.6934, 63.546, 65.409,
     69.723, 72.64, 74.9216, 78.96, 79.904, 83.798,
     85.4678, 87.62, 88.9059, 91.224, 92.9064, 95.94,
     98., 101.07, 102.9055, 106.42, 107.8682, 112.411,
     114.818, 118.710, 121.760, 127.60, 126.9045, 131.293,
     132.9055, 137.327, 138.9055, 140.116, 140.9077, 144.242,
     145., 150.36, 151.964, 157.25, 158.9254, 162.500,
     164.9303, 167.259, 168.9342, 173.04, 174.967, 178.49,
     180.9479, 183.84, 186.207, 190.23, 192.217, 195.084,
     196.9666, 200.59, 204.3833, 207.2, 208.9804, 209.,
     210., 222., 223., 226., 227., 232.0381,
     231.0359, 238.0289, 237., 244., 243., 247.,
     247., 251., 252., 257., 258., 259.,
     262., 261., 262., 266., 264., 277.,
     268., 281., 272., 285., 284., 289.,
     288., 292., 291., 294.
   };

// This routine will return the atomic number of 
int get_atomic_number(REAL_T mass);
#endif
```

`atomic_number.c`:

```c
#include "atomic_number.h"
#include <math.h>

/*
 * Get the atomic number by selecting the atom whose atomic mass is the closest
 * to the atomic mass that is used. This has the advantage of working for all
 * isotopes with the possible exception of tritium (which is closer to He).
 */
int get_atomic_number(REAL_T mass) {
   int i, atomic_num = 0;
   REAL_T min_diff = fabs(mass);
   REAL_T diff;

   for (i = 0; i < NUM_ATOMS; i++) {
      diff = fabs(mass - ATOMIC_MASS[i]);
      if (diff < min_diff) {
         min_diff = diff;
         atomic_num = i;
      }
   }

   return atomic_num;
}
```

Comment: Kind thanks for the comment.  One of the features that the matlab and python implementations above possess is the ability to parse a string representing the formula of a compound, for example `C2H2`, returning the formula weight.  I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: I am not aware of such an implementation. Typically you don't want to do string parsing in C, because you need to look at each character in the string individually and can't apply a regex. It would be easier if the requirement was for C++.